# How to write a single SQL query to single out a subgroup with several conditions

Tags: sql

I have this table:
[image]

I need to get this table:
[image]

One class should correspond to one id. The class is selected as follows:

1. the most common class for id is chosen (for example, id 333 corresponds to class A).
2. but if one id corresponds to the class 'other' and the other classes, then the id is assigned a majoritarian class, while the class 'other' is not considered. In this case, if the number of classes is the same, then the class that was on the last date is assigned. For example, id 111 corresponds to 3 classes ('other', A, B). The number of classes A and B is two. Id 111 is assigned class A, since it was on the last date.
3. if the class is assigned only the class 'other', then the id corresponds to the class 'others' (for example, class 222 is assigned the class 'others', since it is assigned only the class 'others').

Comment: Provide format data instead of image please. what's your dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to select any one row from the subset then you should `RANK` each row by the conditions to order rows in the subset, then filter the rows by the ranking.

You can try this query for your problem.

```
select id, class 
from (
        Select 
            Id
            , Class
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id 
                            ORDER BY 
                                case when class='other' then 0 else 1 end desc -- condition # 3
                                , count(*) desc -- condition # 1
                                , max(date1) desc ) AS RowRank -- condition # 2
        from @table1 
        group by id, class
    ) Q
where rowrank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS is capable of `row_number()` you could first group by `id` and `class` to get the count and the maximum `date1`. Select from that result building the row number partitioned by `id`. As order for the row number use a `CASE` to sort `other` after any other class and then, both descending, the count and the maximum `date1` -- if the counts are equal, the maximum `date1` will decide. The select only the rows where the row number is equal to 1, the first row in the order.

```
SELECT id,
       class
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    class,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                       ORDER BY CASE class
                                                  WHEN 'other'
                                                    THEN 1
                                                  ELSE
                                                    0
                                                END ASC,
                                                c DESC,
                                                d DESC) rn
                    FROM (SELECT id,
                                 class,
                                 count(*) c,
                                 max(date1) d
                                 FROM elbat
                                      GROUP BY id,
                                               class) x) y
       WHERE rn = 1;
```